# Offline time report using Kibana and ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, report, kibana

Our devices are sending pings to ElasticSearch, every 5 minutes, in the following format:

```
{
    deviceId: 34567,
    timestamp: 1514889787
}
```

(We may alter the stored timestamp format if needed).

If the device is offline, the ping is not send at all (ElasticSearch is storing only pings for devices being online). Devices are in different timezones.

The question is:

How to create daily report (or graph), showing both online and offline times?

eg.

```
Date: 02.02.2018  
Device: 34567  

8:00-15:05 Online
15:05-16:25 Offline time (80 minutes)
16:25-17:15 Online
17:15-17:25 Offline time (10 minutes)
```